# Why is App window only opening once and then not opening again?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a app from a tutorial in a book, but I noticed a problem, when the preference window i created is opened and then closed it won't open again, how can i fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT: I saw another post about this but was still un-answered, so i was wondering if you could answer this for me.

EDIT: I am talking about a panel (used a preference pane), it is being opened via a Menu item, and is closed with the cross in the corner of the window. The code I used to create it was from the Book, Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X, the Panel which is being used as a preference pane is in a separate nib file.

EDIT: Here's the code, it's complicated as the tutorial made you create 4 files.

**1) Preferences_Delegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class PreferenceController;

@interface Prefernces_Delegate : NSObject {
    PreferenceController *preferenceController;
}
- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender;

@end
```

**2) Preferences_Delegate.m**

```
#import "Prefernces_Delegate.h"
#import "PreferenceController.h"

@implementation Prefernces_Delegate

- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender
{
    // Is preferenceController nil?
    if (!preferenceController) {
        preferenceController = [[PreferenceController alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"showing %@", preferenceController);
    [preferenceController showWindow:self];
}

@end
```

**3) PreferencesController.h (Not Important)**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController {
    IBOutlet NSButton *checkbox;
}
- (IBAction)changeNewEmptyDoc:(id)sender;
@end
```

**4) PreferencesController.m**

```
#import "PreferenceController.h"


@implementation PreferenceController

- (id)init
{
    if (![super initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"])
        return nil;
    return self;
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Nib file is loaded");
}
- (IBAction)changeNewEmptyDoc: (id)sender
{
    int state = [checkbox state];
        NSLog(@"Checkbox changed %d", state);
}




@end
```

Comment: You might want to add some context to this question. When does it open? How are you closing it? What method are you calling to try and open it?

Comment: Are you purposefully being vague?  "really basic app"? "window is opened and then closed it won't open again"?  "saw another post about this"?  There are so many possible scenarios that you could be referring to, this is ridiculous.

Comment: No, just updated the first post with some more information.

Comment: How big do you want the question to be, you don't want the question to be too long as no one will look at it.

Comment: I don't know much about Cocoa, but since when has that stopped someone on the intertubes?  Is it possible that, although the window is closing, the app itself isn't cleaning up and exiting?

Comment: I don't want the app to close, I want the window to be able to open again after it's been opened once.

Comment: At this point, I'm going to have to join the crowd and point out that some code would be really helpful.

Comment: OK, just editing and posting code now.

Comment: Did you connect the window in your window controller to the panel in IB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Interface Builder, make sure **Release on close** is turned off in the Window's attributes. Also double check that the connections to and from the window from your window controller are hooked up okay.

Comment: How would I connect the windows? Because it didn't say anything about it in the Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I missed a step in the tutorial telling you to connect the window.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the window variable in the windowController is connected to the panel.